# Swift 2.0 Timer for a random number

Tags: swift, nstimer, arc4random

I need a timer that starts when the the app is started. the timer is for a arc4random that gives me a random number from 1 to 10 and based on that number chooses one of multiple if statements. I also need the timer to reset when the random number is given so that a new random number can be given by the arc4random. I have not yet figured out how to implement the timer and arc4random, but i give an example of the if statements below.

Example:

```
if timer <= 9  {

print(A)

}

if timer <= 5 {

print(B)
}

if timer >= 4 {

print(C)
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear -- are you looking to get notified of a random number after a certain number of seconds?  Or are you just trying to populate a variable with a random number generated by arc4random, and then branch depending on the output?

Comment: @tbondwilkinson Sorry for being unclear. I am trying to populate a variable with a random number generated by arc4random, and then branch depending on the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but it sounds like it...

```
var timer = NSTimer()

func viewDidLoad() {
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "getRandomNumber", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func getrandomNumber(){
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(10) + 1)

    if randomNumber >= 9 {
        print("...")
    } else if randomNumber < 9 {
        print("...")
    }
    timer.invalidate()
    resetTimer()
}

func resetTimer() {
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "getRandomNumber", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

when the view loads, the `timer` begins, where it will call the function `getRandomNumber()` every 1.0 seconds. `getRandomNumber()` generates a `randomNumber` and then depending on what the number is you print or do whatever you want accordingly and then after the `if-else` statements  you invalidate the timer, then call a function called `resetTimer`, which will start it all over again.

the random number is generated by `Int(arc4random_uniform(10) + 1)` where 10 is the upper limit and +1 refers to the starting index. So that will generate numbers between 10 and 1. If you did, for example: `Int9arc4random_uniform(20) + 2)`, it would generate numbers between 20 and 2.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
let timer = Int(arc4random_uniform(10) + 1)
if timer < 3 {
  // code
} else if timer < 5 {
  // code
} else {
  // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var randomNumber = Double(arc4random_uniform(10) + 1)

var timer = NSTimer()   
self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(randomNumber, target: self, selector: "AnyFunctionYouWant", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Explanation:

- `randomNumber = Double(arc4random_uniform(10) + 1)` Creates a new var a sets its value to the to return of the arc4random function. You have to cast it to double for it to work with NSTimer class

  `var timer = NSTimer()` Creates a new NSTimer class instance with the default initializer

  `self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(randomNumber, target: self, selector: "AnyFunctionYouWant", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`
  initialize the NSTimer variable you created earlier with a scheduled timer interval which is set as the random number you generated earlier. **If you didn't cast the random number to double it won't work because this method's parameter requires a double not an int**